# add string after finding another one on specific line c#

Tags: c#, arrays, string, linq, richtextbox

I have a `RichTextbox` and I get the text within it as a string using this:

```
 richTextBox2.Lines = richTextBox2.Lines
                                   .Where(line => !line.Contains("any"))
                                   .ToArray();
```

I split the lines and remove the ones containing the string "any".

I want to select certain lines containing another string, then insert a custom string after that.  How can I do that?

Comment: Can you provide an example input and output for what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: You want to add a new line or just add the custom string after the first string on the same line?

Comment: john, I want to add the custom string after the first string on the same line. thanks for editing my question

Comment: Just add a 'Select` and use a `line.Replace` for your old text to "old text + new text"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This adds the custom string right after the found one:

```
richTextBox2.Lines = richTextBox2.Lines
                         .Where(line => !line.Contains("any"))
                         .Select(line => line.Replace("findme", "findme and addme"))
                         .ToArray();
```

This adds the custom string at the end of the line:

```
richTextBox2.Lines = richTextBox2.Lines
                         .Where(line => !line.Contains("any"))
                         .Select(line => 
                             line + (line.Contains("findme") ? " and addme" : "")
                         )
                         .ToArray();
```

Comment: is there a way to keep the text the line had before, but just adding 2 or 3 characters at the end of the whole line? thanks for correcting my question.

Comment: @verax That's exactly what my second example does. Inside of the `Select`, it says "return the line PLUS (if the line has this text, return additional text, otherwise don't add anything)."

Comment: yes, I didn't refresh the site did not see it, Thank you so much

Comment: I'm sorry Moshe, what if I want to select a line that starts with "any"?

Comment: Use `line.StartsWith` instead of `line.Contains `.

Comment: thank you, the last thing I would like to do is swapping 2 strings, (the first one would be on the second place and the second one on the first place)
forgive me, I'm still trying, but can't get it